# How to add a Splash Screen in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

i want to add a splash screen before the setup starts. I do not find an idea. I have tried following piece of code in a post but I am not getting the splash screen.

```
[setup]
AppName=Slash PNG
AppVerName=1.0
DefaultDirName={pf}\program

[Languages]
Name: "spanish"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Spanish.isl"

[Files]
Source: IsUtilsHb.dll; DestDir: {app}; Flags: dontcopy
Source: SplashScreen.png; DestDir: {app}; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]
function SplashScreen(hWnd: Integer; pathPng: String; nSleep: Integer): Integer;
external 'SplashScreen@files:IsUtilsHb.dll stdcall';

procedure InitializeWizard();
var 
  SplashFileName: string;
begin
  SplashFileName := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\SplashScreen.png');
  ExtractTemporaryFile('SplashScreen.png');
  SplashScreen(StrToInt(ExpandConstant('{hwnd}')), SplashFileName, 5000);
end;
```

--My code is as below

```
#define MyAppName "My Program"
#define MyAppVersion "1.5"
#define MyAppPublisher "My Company, Inc."
#define MyAppURL "http://www.example.com/"
#define MyAppExeName "MyProg.exe"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{08CBDC11-A20E-49F7-A482-C384130DAC65}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppName}
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppName}
OutputBaseFilename=setup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "E:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\Examples\MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: E:\BUILD\Splash Screen\isgsg.dll; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: ignoreversion dontcopy nocompression
Source: E:\BUILD\Splash Screen\*; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: ignoreversion dontcopy nocompression
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

[Code]
    procedure ShowSplashScreen(p1:HWND;p2:string;p3,p4,p5,p6,p7:integer;p8:boolean;p9:Cardinal;p10:integer); external 'ShowSplashScreen@files:isgsg.dll stdcall delayload';

```
procedure InitializeWizard();
var 
  SplashFileName: string;
begin
  //SplashFileName := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\test2.bmp');
  SplashFileName := 'E:\BUILD\Splash Screen\Manas.png';
  //ExtractTemporaryFile('test2.bmp');
  //SplashScreen(StrToInt(ExpandConstant('{hwnd}')), SplashFileName, 2000);
 ShowSplashScreen(WizardForm.Handle,SplashFileName,1000,3000,1000,0,255,True,$FFFFFF,10);
end;
```

Comment: This plugin seems to export a function called `ShowSplashScreen`. Try to use that one. For the one you have used one would need to create a window I guess.

Comment: i have tried the code and not getting the splash screen.